# sklearn Ridgecv cross validation iterable

Tags: scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am confused about the parameter cv in `RidgeCV` of `sklearn.linear_model`

Indeed, I already have my data splitted into a training set and validation set, and the documentation of `RidgeCV` says the parameter `cv` can be an iterable yielding train/test splits. So I write the following:

```
m = linear_model.RidgeCV(cv=zip(x_validation, y_validation))
m.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

But it does not work.

Python throws the following error

```
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

What is wrong with my understanding of the parameter `cv` and is there an easy manner to use my own and already splitted validation set?

Answer (score 2):

it seems the parameter cv expects a list of indices for use as training set and list of indices for use as validation set, so a solution

```
x = np.concatenate(x_train, x_validation)
y = np.concatenate(y_train, y_validation)
train_fraction = 0.9
train_indices = range(int(train_fraction * x.shape[0]))
validation_indices = range(int(train_fraction * x.shape[0]), x.shape[0])
m = linear_model.RidgeCV(cv=zip(train_indices, validation_indices))
m.fit(x, y)
```